# State space equation of CARMA(p,q) processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, sde, differential-equations, arima

Thanks for visting my question:)
I am currently working on Carma(p,q) processes and do not understand how to derive the state equation. So the CARMA(p,q) process is defined by:
for $p>q$
the process is def. by:
\begin{align*}
a(D)C_t=b(D)DB_t
\end{align*}
$D=\frac{d}{dt}$
$a(z)=z^p+a_1z^{p-1}+...+a_p$
$b(z)=b_0+b_1z+...+b_qz^q$
The **State Space representation** is given by:
Observation state:

\begin{align*}
C_t=BX_t
\end{align*}
Sate equation:

\begin{align*}
dX_t=AX_tdt+edB_t
\end{align*}
with
$B=[b_0,b_1,...,b_q,0,...,0 ]$, $e=[0,0,...,0,1]$ and $X_t=(X_{t,0},...,X_{t,p-1} )$
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\\
    -a_p &-a_{p-1} & -a_{p-2} & \vdots & -a_1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$\

**My attempt**:

1. Oberservation equation:

\begin{align*}
a(D)C_t&=b(D)DB_t\\
\Leftrightarrow C_t&=a^{-1}(D)b(D)DB_t\\
\Leftrightarrow C_t&=b(D)a^{-1}(D)DB_t\\
\Leftrightarrow C_t&=b(D) X_t\\
\Leftrightarrow  C_t&= (b_0,b_1,...,b_q,0,...,0)X_t
\end{align*}
with $X_t=a^{-1}(D)DB_t$
and $X_t=(X_{t,0},...,X_{t,p-1} )$
2.)State equation:
\begin{align*}
X_t&=a^{-1}(D)DB_t\\
\Leftrightarrow (D^p+a_1D^{p-1}+...+a_p)X_t&=DB_t\\
\Leftrightarrow &????
\end{align*}

**Questions**:

Is my approach correct?
And if so, how can I proceed?